# What does conceive anything do with Longshanks' honor?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> ROBERT: As bride for his son, Longshanks had chosen  the daughter of
> his rival, the King of France.It was widely  whispered that for **the
> princess to conceive, Longshanks would  have to do the honors himself**.

What does conceive anything do with Longshanks' honor?

Does it mean Longshanks have sex with princess to make his son to be father?

Source: [Braveheart (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. *Do the hono[u]rs* is a set phrase. https://www.lexico.com/definition/do_the_honours . In this context, it means *carry out the necessary actions*. It has nothing to do with his personal honour.

Comment: Does it mean Longshanks have sex with princess to make his son to be father?

Comment: I've already told you - Yes, it does.